# Code to compare cells with a range in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, classification

I am trying to write a code which can compare a cell with a range. In this case, i have a code which takes average of a set of data within specific ranges and then when it is done i want it to compare the cells to see if the value in the cell is within the range and if it is smaller that the average , then display 1 if not display 2.
For example i have a data like this:

```
0.1 , 0.6 , 1.1 , 0.15 , 0.55
```

First i take averages of numbers between 0.5 , 1, 1.5. Average of the numbers above are:

```
range    average
 0.5       0.125
 1.0       0.575
 1.5       1.1
```

Then, i want to compare the cells, if the first value is between 0 and 0.5 and smaller than the average of its range, show 1 and if it is greater than its average show 2. if it is between 0.5 and 1 and smaller than the average of its range, show 3 and if greater show 4 and so one.So, the numbers shown above would make a map like this:

```
  1 , 4 , 5 , 2 , 3
```

My code is :

```
% Indexes
row = 1;
col = 1;
range = 1;
% Constants
MAX_RANGE = 5;
MAX_DISPLAY_VALUE = 10;
HIGH_ERROR = 2.5;
LOW_ERROR = 0.0;
% Range Value variables
rangeValue = zeros(1, MAX_RANGE);
rangeTotalForAverages = zeros(1, MAX_RANGE);
rangeAveragesCount = zeros(1, MAX_RANGE);
rangeCount = zeros(1, MAX_RANGE);
rangeAverage = zeros(1, MAX_RANGE);
% Display Value Varibales
displayValue = zeros(MAX_DISPLAY_VALUE);
displayValueCount = zeros(MAX_DISPLAY_VALUE);
% Set up the range bounds
rangeValue(1) = 0.5;
rangeValue(2) = 1.0;
rangeValue(3) = 1.5;
rangeValue(4) = 2.0;
rangeValue(5) = 2.5;
% Read the file
rawData = dlmread('data_1.csv',',');
% Get the size
[MAX_ROWS, MAX_COLS] = size(rawData);
% Map arrays
errorMap = double(zeros(MAX_ROWS, MAX_COLS));
classificationMap = double(zeros(MAX_ROWS, MAX_COLS));
% A function to round up 
value = ceil(rawData(row, col)*1000)/1000;
% Print the raw data
fprintf('Raw Data\n');
for row = 1 : MAX_ROWS
for col = 1 : MAX_COLS
    fprintf('%0.3f ', rawData(row, col));
end
fprintf('\n');
end 
% Print the Error Map
fprintf('Error Map\n');
for row = 1 : MAX_ROWS
for col = 1 : MAX_COLS
    if rawData(row, col) > HIGH_ERROR
        errorMap(row, col) = rawData(row, col);
        rawData(row, col) = HIGH_ERROR;
        if rawData(row, col) < LOW_ERROR
        errorMap(row, col) = rawData(row, col);
        rawData(row, col) = LOW_ERROR;   
        end
    end
fprintf('%0.3f ', errorMap(row, col));
end
fprintf('\n');
end
% Print the Rounded Data
fprintf('Rounded Data\n');
for row = 1 : MAX_ROWS
for col = 1 : MAX_COLS
    value = ceil(rawData(row, col)*1000)/1000;
    fprintf('%0.3f ', value);
end
fprintf('\n');
end
% Calculate and store the averages for each range
for row = 1 : MAX_ROWS
for col = 1 : MAX_COLS
  value = ceil(rawData(row, col)*1000)/1000; 
  for range = 1 : MAX_RANGE
    if value <= rangeValue(range)
        rangeTotalForAverages(range) = rangeTotalForAverages(range) + value;
        rangeAveragesCount(range) = rangeAveragesCount(range) + 1;
        rangeCount(range) = rangeCount(range) + 1;  
        break
    end
  end
end   
end
for range = 1 : MAX_RANGE
if rangeAveragesCount(range) > 0
    rangeAverage(range) = rangeTotalForAverages(range) / 
rangeAveragesCount(range);
end
end
% Print the average
fprintf('Average\n');
for range = 1 : MAX_RANGE
fprintf('%0.3f ', rangeAverage(range));
fprintf('\n');
end
% Create the Classification Map
tempDisplayValueIndex = 0;
for row = 1 : MAX_ROWS
for col = 1 : MAX_COLS
  value = ceil(rawData(row, col)*1000)/1000;
  for range = 1 : MAX_RANGE
      % If the value is in the range
   if value <= rangeValue(range) 
       % If the value is less than the average for the range, set the 
 display value
   tempDisplayValueIndex = range * 2;
   if value <= rangeAverage(range)
   classificationMap(row, col) = displayValue(tempDisplayValueIndex);
   displayValueCount(tempDisplayValueIndex) = 
displayValueCount(tempDisplayValueIndex) + 1;
   else
       % Store the classification map and count the display value
   classificationMap(row, col) = displayValue(tempDisplayValueIndex + 1); 
   displayValueCount(tempDisplayValueIndex) = 
displayValueCount(tempDisplayValueIndex) + 1;
   break;
   end
   end
  end
end
end
% Print the Classification Map
fprintf("\n Classification Map \n");
for row = 1 : MAX_ROWS
for col = 1 : MAX_COLS
fprintf('%f ', classificationMap(row, col)); 
end
fprintf('\n');
end
```

It only prints zero for all the values!! 
Any help would be much appropriated.

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure without the .csv file, but let's have a look: you have a `classificationMap`-element always zero.

If you look at your code it seems that the line in which you fill this matrix is

```
classificationMap(row, col) = displayValue(tempDisplayValueIndex);
```

or

```
classificationMap(row, col) = displayValue(tempDisplayValueIndex + 1);
```

so where do you put values into displayValue? Trying CTRL+F in your code, the other line when this variable is assigned I found only this line

```
displayValue = zeros(MAX_DISPLAY_VALUE);
```

so this variable is created filled with zeros at the beginning and never modified later.

I think that, if your FOR cycle works with `value`, the answer could be

```
classificationMap(row, col) = value
```

(I can't be sure without trying the code).